# type 'xFile' is not subtype 'File'

Tags: flutter, dart

```
lass _ImageRectScreenState extends State<ImageRectScreen> {
  Rect _rect, _objectRect, _referenceRect;
  Offset _start, _finish;
  PageController _pageViewController = PageController();
  Future<XFile> _image;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _image = _getImage();
  }

  var picker = ImagePicker();
  Future<XFile> _getImage() async {
    return await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: LayoutBuilder(
              builder: (context, _) => Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Positioned.fill(
                    child: FutureBuilder<XFile>(
                      future: _image,
                      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.hasData) {
                          return CustomPaint(
                            child: Image.file(snapshot.data),
                            foregroundPainter: MyRectPainter(rect: _rect),
                          );
                        } else {
                          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned.fill(
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onPanDown: (detail) {
                        setState(() {
                          _start = detail.localPosition;
                        });
                      },
                      onPanUpdate: (detail) {
                        setState(() {
                          _finish = detail.localPosition;
                          _rect = Rect.fromPoints(_start, _finish);
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

When i run a the code the camera works normally and i can select next , but as soon as i want to measure the image it gives me xFile is not a subtype of type 'file' even though no errors are shown on the code, bare in mind my sdk is version 2.10.0 because my whole app is based on that version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the path of Xfile to File() to get the desired conversion. Update your custom paint as:-

```
CustomPaint(
   child: Image.file(File(snapshot.data.path)),
   foregroundPainter: MyRectPainter(rect: _rect),
);
```

Comment: Its now giving me Type String is not a subtype of File

Comment: Have you added File()?

Comment: yes when i added the File() it gave me this error

Comment: The argument type 'File (where File is defined in C:\src\Flutter\flutter\bin\cache\pkg\sky_engine\lib\html\html_dart2js.dart)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'File (where File is defined in

Comment: import 'dart:io'; add this in place of dart:html

Comment: Np, you can accept the answer by clicking on tick button next to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Terminal run following commands

```
flutter clean
flutter pub cache repair
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use**          `child: Image.file(File(snapshot.data.path)),`

**instead of**   `child: Image.file(snapshot.data),`